# Scroll Android listview by some percentage

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll

Is there a way to scroll (no animation) a `ListView` by a given percentage e.g. `1.0` would scroll to the last element, `0.0` would scroll to first element.

**EDIT**

I don't want to scroll to a given element, I need pixel scrolling. So if there is only 3 items, scrolling 0.75 would scroll to close to half the last item.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the method `scrollListBy(pixels)` is what you're looking for.

> Scrolls the list items within the view by a specified number of pixels.

More info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#scrollListBy(int)

Comment: I don't want to scroll `by`, I want to scroll `to`

Comment: What's the difference?, the important thing is the result you're looking for.

Comment: Also only available from API level 19